# deploying solidity code using nodejs getting error below i share the code

Tags: javascript, node.js, deployment, ethereum, solidity

first i present solidity compilation code Compile.js

```
const path = require('path');
const solc = require('solc');
const fs = require('fs-extra');

const buildPath = path.resolve(__dirname, 'build');
fs.removeSync(buildPath);

const campaignPath = path.resolve(__dirname, 'contracts', 'Campaign.sol');
const source = fs.readFileSync(campaignPath, 'UTF-8');

var input = {
    language: 'Solidity',
    sources: {
        'Campaign.sol' : {
            content: source
        }
    },
    settings: {
        outputSelection: {
            '*': {
                '*': [ '*' ]
            }
        }
    }
};

var output = JSON.parse(solc.compile(JSON.stringify(input)));
fs.ensureDirSync(buildPath);

for(contractName in output.contracts['Campaign.sol']){
    fs.outputJSONSync(
        path.resolve(buildPath, contractName + '.json'),
        output.contracts['Campaign.sol'][contractName]
    );
}
```

which of my compilation code is right or wrong?

here is my deploy.js

```
const HDWalletProvider = require('truffle-hdwallet-provider');
const Web3 = require('web3');
const compiledFactory = require('./build/CampaignFactory.json');

const provider = new HDWalletProvider(
    // process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_META_MASK,
    // process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_INFURA_API
    'dove poppih solid recycle impose piano leisure twin pyramid afraid spolik nose',
    'https://sepolia.infura.io/v3/fcuijy7e97ee2f475da508dc6d1dc42701'
);

const web3 = new Web3(provider);

const deploy = async () => {
    const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();
    console.log('attempting to deploy from account: ', accounts[0]);

    const result = await new web3.eth.Contract(compiledFactory.abi)
    .deploy({data: compiledFactory.evm.bytecode.object})
    .send( {from:accounts[0], gas:'125653'});

    console.log('Contract deployed to: ', result.options.address);
    provider.engine.stop();
};

deploy();
```

for the above code im getting error

```
attempting to deploy from account:  0x909CD220D8707e052C0a6E94FA167227fFfc7865
node:internal/process/promises:279
            triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);
            ^

Error: insufficient funds for gas * price + value
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be a bug in geth, keep in mind that this error is common if you don't have enough `ETH` in your account, if your `node` isn't in sync with the network, or if you don't **specify a gas price** or something else is slightly wrong with the command.

> gas * price + value really means MAXGas * price

You can try this [solution](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/2173) to convert all values to `hex` (with bc if you use bash) and make sure to specify both (gas and gasPrice), and enclosing all values in **single quotes**:

```sol
eth.sendTransaction({from:'0x123456', to:'0x123456', value: '0x8AC4270ACC4B7FF7', gas: '0x5208', gasPrice: '0x4A817C800'});"
```

Other solution could be '**downgrade version**', because sometimes it accidentally cuses this issue.